# Ignore regular expression in R with gsub

Tags: r, regex, gsub

```
df <- data.frame(
    videos = c("Moon vs Grubby", "Moon vs Happy", "Happy vs Th00"),
    links = c("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QlNc-jb4ESk&t", "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VESO8YQVFSE", "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RI3IJT8ZzBM")
)

df$links <- as.character(df$links)
df$links <- gsub("watch?v=", "embed/", df$links)
```

I have got the following code with links to YouTube which I want to embed in a shiny App. However YouTube needs to replace part of the string which is interpreted as a regular expression. I did not find a helpful solution here.

So how can I `gsub` this pattern?

Current Links:
`https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QlNc-jb4ESk&t`

Expected Outcome:
`https://www.youtube.com/embed/=QlNc-jb4ESk&t`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We need to escape the `?` and `=` as these are metacharacters

```
gsub("watch\\?v\\=", "embed/=", df$links)
```

or with `fixed = TRUE`

```
gsub("watch?v=", "embed/=", df$links, fixed = TRUE)
```

Also, as there is only a single instance, we can use `sub`

```
sub("watch?v=", "embed/=", df$links, fixed = TRUE)
#[1] "https://www.youtube.com/embed/=QlNc-jb4ESk&t" 
#[2] "https://www.youtube.com/embed/=VESO8YQVFSE"  
#[3] "https://www.youtube.com/embed/=RI3IJT8ZzBM"
```

Answer (score 2):

My guess is that this expression might work:

```
(\S*)watch\?v=(\S*)
```

The expression is explained on the top right panel of [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/3yMijb/1/), if you wish to explore further or modify it, and in [this link](https://regex101.com/r/3yMijb/1/debugger), you can watch how it would match against some sample inputs step by step, if you like.

and our code might look like:

```
gsub("(\\S*)watch\\?v\\=(\\S*)", "\\1embed/\\2", df$links)
```

My guess is that this would be the desired output:

```
https://www.youtube.com/embed/QlNc-jb4ESk&t
```